# resize2fs fails on "Scanning inode table"

Tags: partition, gparted, resize2fs

I consistently receive this exact error when attempting to shrink a partition on my system. This partition houses xubuntu, which has been giving me some strange errors about the disk on boot which I will add to my answer ASAP (see edit)

Screenshot to preserve original formatting of `gparted` output, followed by the raw text:
[image: original formatting]

```
GParted 0.26.1 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2

Shrink /dev/sda8 from 186.22 GiB to 52.14 GiB  00:00:15    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda8  00:00:02    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda8 (partition)
start: 569604096
end: 960141311
size: 390537216 (186.22 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda8 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:10    ( SUCCESS )

e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sda8  00:00:10    ( SUCCESS )

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information 

344770 inodes used (2.82%, out of 12206080)
697 non-contiguous files (0.2%)
437 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 285823/147
5381900 blocks used (11.02%, out of 48817152)
0 bad blocks
1 large file

250061 regular files
30196 directories
55 character device files
25 block device files
1 fifo
12 links
64422 symbolic links (58710 fast symbolic links)
1 socket
------------
344773 files
e2fsck 1.43.1 (08-Jun-2016)
shrink file system  00:00:03    ( ERROR )

resize2fs -p /dev/sda8 54675456K  00:00:03    ( ERROR )

Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda8 to 13668864 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 3 (max = 1490)
Scanning inode table XXX-------------------------------------
resize2fs 1.43.1 (08-Jun-2016)
========================================
```

EDIT: Did some searching, boot errors seem to be associated with a misconfigured swap, will deal with that later.

Comment: Your transcript with randomly reformatted lines is unreadable. Please copy-paste the actual transcript and use the code formatting tool (Ctrl+K or the `{}` button).

Comment: Sorry about that. Posted a screenshot of the html output instead and put the raw text in a pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with GParted 0.26.1-5 (which had resize2fs 1.43.1), when trying to shrink an ext4 partition.

I succeeded with an old version of resize2fs (1.42.8).
You can use the old Parted Magic iso (2013.08.01, the last free version).